# Why do we need extra hashing if we could use simpler scheme?

Tags: hash, mac

Lets say that we use init vector IV, key K and HMAC key H. Message is M.

Mode of operation is CBC !!!

We usually encrypt this way:

```
C = crypt(M,K,IV) #encrypted data  
R = C + MAC(C)  # final result and + is for con cat
```

But we could just use:

```
R = len + crypt(M + H,K, IV)  # notice M + H
```

Is there something wrong with such a scheme? It looks much faster to me and requires like half the computation and complexity.

Comment: Yes, it does not give message authenticity and it leaves crypt accessible to chosen-ciphertext attacks.

Comment: If HMAC is too slow for you, I'd look into authenticated encryption modes. They use much faster MAC techniques.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This scheme is totally insecure. If an attacker modifies any part of the ciphertext except the last block before the ciphertext corresponding to `H`, your scheme won't catch it.

CBC decryption of a block only depends on the ciphertext of the previous and current block.[image: Illustration]

*(Based on [Cbc decryption.png](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cbc_decryption.png) from Wikipedia)*

The red parts are left totally unprotected by your MAC scheme. The green parts affect your MAC, but even on them there are some attacks.

Comment: Oh, I see, what about replacing whit some other mode. That propagates trough all

Comment: That depends on the exact mode.

Comment: Crazy, I just had a similar thought earlier today after getting pissed off at HMAC, but using CFB instead. I came to the same conclusion after a few minutes, the diagram illustrates it all very neatly, +1.